# Imagemagick: How to bulk convert images into square

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-resizing

I want the size of the square should be equal to the largest side of the original photo

E.g.

Original: 500 x 400 => Output:500 x 500
Original: 400 x 600 => Output: 600 x 600

Comment: Are you using ImageMagick 6 or ImageMagick 7.  It is easy in IM 7.

Comment: You will need to write a script "for" loop to process all the images. What is your OS/platform, since scripting language is different for Windows vs Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that as follows for any given image in Imagemagick 7. To do multiple image, you would need to write a "for" loop, whose syntax depends upon your OS.

```
magick image.suffix -gravity center -background black -extent "%wx%h^" result.suffix
```

or

```
magick image.suffix -gravity center -background black -extent "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]" result.suffix
```

Comment: the bad thing is that the height and width are not the same in all the photos, can i get w,h dynamically for each photo?

Comment: See my new answer. It allows you to get that dynamically and for all images in a folder. In my first answer, it does get the dimensions dynamically in either case that I showed, but only works on one image at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to convert all images in a folder with either Imagemagick 6 or 7. I use -distort SRT's viewport to do the padding with a no-op warping (i.e. no rotation, scale or translation) in mogrify to process all images in the folder.

First create a new folder to hold your output images, if desired and use the -path option to mogrify. Specify a background color (in this case I use red).

For Imagemagick 7:

```
magick mogrify -path path_to/new_folder -virtual-pixel background -background red -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]-%[fx:0.5*(max(w,h)-w)]-%[fx:0.5*(max(w,h)-h)]" +distort srt 0 *
```

For Imagemagick 6, remove "magick" before mogrify.